# ACPI 30k+ interrupts per second

Tags: power-management, battery, acpi, cpu

My computer is currently doing something like 30k+ interrupts per second. This causes battery issues as well as the CPU being always stuck at the highest speed, making it very hot (overheating.. 75C at IDLE)

Powertop info:

```
99.4% (32052.4) [acpi] <interrupt>
0.3% (115.9) [iwlagn] <interrupt>
```

Just to clarify this started suddenly a couple of days ago. It didn't have this issue before (though I had a tonne of headaches with Linux on my computer in general..)

Comment: What is the laptop's make and model?

Comment: Lenovo IdeaPad Y460. The most ubuntu-incompatible laptop of all time. (Issue after issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason apparently lies with the BIOS. Something has changed the BIOS... which caused this problem. Fixed via a reflash of the latest BIOS image from the Lenovo's support site under Windows.

I noticed when Windows had the same issue of interrupts taking a lot of CPU, which happened to originate from ACPI.sys

The only thing I installed prior to this happening was the fglrx 11.7 update... IDK if this had anything to do with it, but it's the only thing that I've installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try unloading the `ibm_acpi` module ([Source](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/known.php#ibm_acpi))

Comment: Don't have that module.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Linux boot params `acpi=noirq`, sometimes I find I have the same problem I don't know why, when I added this params, no more `acpi` interrupts.