# Screen flickers on a Lenovo y460 laptop

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, flicker

I have a lenovo y460 laptop with hybrid graphics. it's a nvidia optimus card and a integrated intel graphics.

I'm only using the integrated chip and  i don't want use the nvidia card

the problem occur in ubuntu 10.04 and ubuntu 11.10

i can not work when the flickering occur .

that all right in windows 7 so i think it's a driver or kernel problem

i have try the `i915.powersave=0` but it's no use

and `i915.modeset=1` make the resultion horrible

the only clue is the xorg.0.log,when the flickering occur the xorg.0.log full with :

```
[  2868.431] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   71.00  1366 1414 1446 1502  768 771 776 788 -hsync -vsync (47.3 kHz)
[  2873.979] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  2873.979] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   71.00  1366 1414 1446 1502  768 771 776 788 -hsync -vsync (47.3 kHz)
[  2874.479] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 654
[  2874.479] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  2874.479] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   71.00  1366 1414 1446 1502  768 771 776 788 -hsync -vsync (47.3 kHz)
[  2881.539] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 654
[  2881.539] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  2881.539] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   71.00  1366 1414 1446 1502  768 771 776 788 -hsync -vsync (47.3 kHz)
[  2881.539] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 654
[  2881.539] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  2881.539] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   71.00  1366 1414 1446 1502  768 771 776 788 -hsync -vsync (47.3 kHz)
```

i don't know who output the information

and there is another clue when the flickering occur ,i switch to tty1 (crtl+alt+F1) ,i found there some char "^@" output to the screen. even when the os boot i found the char "^@" occur in the screen

**update:**
my problem maybe is a acpi problem so i have try below kernel params:

```
acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor acpi=copy_dsdt nohz=off highres=off acpi=noirq pcie_aspm=force
```

you also could try:

```
 acpi=off nolapic
```

but it's a nuclear way because it make another problem

Comment: `^@` is a null byte. Has a key on your keyboard got stuck?

Comment: @Lekensteyn  no i have check the keybord. and i found other people have the problem. i guess it's linux don't support my hardware??

Comment: when the char "^@" occur ,the xorg.0.log are full with the information which i have menction above

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem on a Dell Inspiron 15R. 
Try this, it worked for me!

Open the terminal and run: 
`xinput list`

Try to find this entry:
`↳ Video Bus id=8 [slave  keyboard (3)]`

Get the "id" and disable it running:
`sudo xinput set-prop 8 "Device Enabled" 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try reflashing your BIOS. The ACPI tables that you showed on https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/7 are incomplete.

The BIOS can be downloaded from http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/sg/en/DriversDownLoads/drivers_show_2612.html

A similar issue: [ACPI 30k+ interrupts per second](https://askubuntu.com/q/56278/6969) (this time with a Lenovo Y460, but with AMD graphics!)

Comment: i already update my bios before,but no use for this,so it's maybe a hardware problem.

Comment: Have you tried applying the same update again?

Comment: i have try the new bios again,but it no effect.if it really is a bios problem , why windows 7 no this error,the bios only supprot the windows ???

Comment: use kernel params nolapic can make this error disapper,but my core i3 multi core became only one.

Comment: The option "noacpi" may solve the issue, but it also disables a lot PM functionality like suspend. Maybe Lenocrap is providing drivers which does some houskeeping that should be done by BIOS.